# golang windows service package initialize settings

Tags: go

I am trying to create a golang windows service utilizing this package

```
godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc
```

Everything works great until I add an init func to initialize settings. The service then fails to start.  I am attempting to load config.json via this package

```
github.com/spf13/viper
```

The error I get then is:

could not start service: the service did not response to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Comment: What is the error or output from your go app?

Comment: I only get an error when I try to start the service... it is "could not start service: the service did not response to the start or control request in a timely fashion."

if I run in debug or install/remove it works fine

Comment: You need to find the error that happens when you start the service. For example, is there a permissions problem reading a config file?

Comment: I am still working on it with no luck :(  everything I add to a fun Init on the main.go results in this error

"**** service failed to start due to the following error: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."

I am very new to go, so besides elog and log I am not sure what else to do to find the issue.

Answer (score 2):

@JimB thank you.  that was it,

running in debug it looks in the folder that the exe is in, 
when running in service it looks in the system32 folder.

I installed github.com/kardianos/osext 
and used the func ExecutableFolder() to get back to the main folder of the exe file.  Which then allowed it to find my config file and load.